# Lua script error: Module Not Found: documentation, despite Module:Documentation being imported from Wikipedia

Tags: mediawiki

As title suggests,
I am following this guide:
https://m.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Importing_Wikipedia_infoboxes_tutorial

I have exported as per instructions wikipedias Module:documentation
However when I go to various info box templates such as Template:Infobox_tool all I see is
Script error: No such module "documentation".

Don't quite know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I think I can guess what the problem is.

On Wikipedia, page names always start with a capital letter. So if you go to the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/apple, it will redirect you to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple. The same extends to template names and module names, so `Module:documentation` will redirect you to `Module:Documentation`.

However, if you set the [`$wgCapitalLinksthis` option](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgCapitalLinks) to false in your LocalSettings.php, you can override this behaviour, and make all the page names completely case-sensitive. I'm guessing that's what you've done in your installation.

If this is the case, then you will break any templates imported from Wikipedia that assume that page names always start with a capital letter (i.e. they use code like `{{#invoke:documentation|main}}` instead of `{{#invoke:Documentation|main}}`). In my experience, there are a lot of templates that do this. And it's not just Lua modules; the same thing happens when you transclude a template.

There are two solutions to this problem - the easy one, and the hard one. The easy one is to make all page names start with a capital letter by setting `$wgCapitalLinks = true;` in your LocalSettings.php (or just by removing `$wgCapitalLinks = false;`). If you don't want to do that, then you're left with the hard one: check all the templates that you import and make sure they use the correct capitalisation of the module names.

In your situation, going to `Template:Documentation` and changing the code from `{{#invoke:documentation|main}}` to `{{#invoke:Documentation|main}}` will likely fix your immediate problem.

There is also a [maintenance script](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:CleanupCaps.php) that you can use to fix broken links in pages, and broken template transclusions. At the moment, though, this script won't fix broken #invoke statements, though, as normal redirects don't work in the Module namespace, so you'll have to do those manually.